# Ngrx : Dispatch expected an object

Tags: angular, ngrx

in my Actions I have:

```
export const GetSwivlr = createAction(
  GET_SWIVLR,
  props<{ payload: Swivlr[] }>()
);......
```

in my reducer I have:

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(SwivlrActions.AddSwivlr, (state, { payload }) => {
    return adapter.addOne(payload, state)
  }),
  on(SwivlrActions.RemoveSwivlr, (state, { payload }) => {
    return adapter.removeOne(payload, state)
  }),
  on(SwivlrActions.GetSwivlr, (state, { payload }) => {
    return adapter.setAll(payload, state)
  })
);
```

in my effects I have:

```
export class SwivlrEffects {
  constructor(private crudService: CrudService,
    private readonly actions$: Actions
  ) { }

  public readonly getSwivlr$ = createEffect(() => 
     this.actions$.pipe(ofType(GetSwivlr),
      mergeMap(() => this.crudService.getAll<Swivlr[]>('endpointAddress').pipe(
        map(swivlr => ({ type: GET_SWIVLR, payload: swivlr})))),
      catchError((error: string | null) =>
         of(FailSwivlr))
    )
  );
}
```

Originally, All my actions had been declared as functions as opposed to const and I was returning each as an Action as opposed to createAction.

Using the dispatcher with my Actions declared as functions, didn't cause any errors when I did:

```
this.store.dispatch({ type: GET_SWIVLR });
```

but now it does, I thought that I just needed to change the call to be:

```
this.store.dispatch(GetSwivlr());
```

However, this const has a props attached. This is what I believe will get populated from my effect after a successful call to my Api.

Can someone suggest how I should be changing this call?

I receive 2 errors the first:

> Error: Effect "SwivlrEffects.getSwivlr$" dispatched as invalid action:
> undefined

second error:

> TypeError: Dispatch expected an object, instead it received a
> function.

To Elaborate on @Antons answer in my component I now have:

```
....
 tiles$: Observable<Swivlr[]> = this.store.select(state => state.tiles);

  returnval: Swivlr[];

  constructor(private store: Store<{tiles: Swivlr[] }>) {
    this.returnval = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(GetSwivlr({ payload: this.returnval }));
    }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

As you declared here:

```
export const GetSwivlr = createAction(
  GET_SWIVLR,
  props<{ payload: Swivlr[] }>()
);
```

You have to provide payload to your action and dispatch it like this:

```
this.store.dispatch(GetSwivlr({ payload: `here is your object with type Swivlr[]` }));
```

Comment: I declared an property of type Swivlr[]  and then declared as per your example, however I still receive the same errors in the browser as before

Comment: This is definitely correct, you need to set the payload like this

Answer (score 0):

In your effect you do not dispatch a proper action upon finishing it. You probably did not update it when you changed your actions to the `createAction` version. The brackets in the code below might be messed up - be warned.

It also should probably be `SetSwivlr({ payload: swivlr })`?

```js
getSwivlr$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(GetSwivlr),
        mergeMap(() => this.crudService.getAll<Swivlr[]>('endpointAddress').pipe(
          map(swivlr => GetSwivlr({ payload: swivlr })))), // <-- here
          catchError((error: string | null) => of(FailSwivlr))
    )
  );
}
```

Another remark, when selecting from the store you should use  [ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors) instead of doing `this.store.select(state => state.tiles)` in the component.